# How do I get Minecraft on a non-linux chromebook

Tags: chromebook, minecraft

So I am trying to get Minecraft on a non-linux compatilble chromebook and **Without the Google play store** I am trying to get Minecraft for free legally and as luck would have it there is a way https://minecraft.net/download
but it appears no one cares about ChromeOS anymore because https://Minecraft.net/download says Google play store but as I said **Without the Google play store** so yeah, I need some help!